# How to get Text of Dropdownlistfor without script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I Search so many example but not find any suitable answer on it. 
I have to get Text of Dropdownlistfor but it Pass Value mean id always.
**Not using Jquery or Javascript.**

Comment: It the `value` of the selected option which is submitted. If the `value` is not the same as the display text, then you cant without using javascipt. But why do you think you need to post the display text? - if you need it again in the POST method, just get it from your repository based on the posted value.

Comment: dropdownlistfor is static and when i post ..it gives Value but i have to use text of dropdown to filter data. dropdown list has three static value like 'High' , 'Normal' and 'Low'..so that i have make it static but when i post data..the model passes Value .how can pass Text to method ? and Model has string filled of Priority..which i pass..from model

Comment: Then make the values `High`, `Normal` and `Low`!

Comment: ohh..!!! got it thanx...